# What do they call postmasters in the UK?

Tags: word-request, british-english

I need to send a package to a postmaster in a Commonwealth country. What do they call postmasters in the British dialect? It might be the same word, but I just want to make sure they don't call them something else.

Comment: it's the same. They also have subpostmasters.

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/postmaster Does a dictionary not answer this?

Answer (score 2):

I see that there is a Postmaster General of the UK, as well as a general postmasters' exam. So I'm gonna go with "postmaster."